# How to Get a Count of Radio Button Value in PHP?

Tags: php

I have a simple question here, How to find the Radio button value(s) count from an HTML form using the PHP POST method. Below is the HTML form code and I would like to get the below values in check_result.php

````
$total_One_Count="";
$total_two_Count="";
$total_three_Count="";
$total_Four_Count="";
$total_Five_Count="";

Please help me to get this result.

       
   ``` <form class="form-inline" action="check_result.php" class="text-center" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">    
     <div class="border-secondary border border-0  shadow-lg border-secondary mt-2 mb-2">
    <p class="p-3 bg-opacity-10 mb-0 w400">1. I Move my savings into investments on a regular basis. They don’t lie idle in bank savings account.</p>     
    <div class="bg-success p-3 text-dark bg-opacity-10 shadow-sm">       
       <div class="form-check form-check-inline ">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="q[0]"  value="one" required>
  <label class="form-check-label">I Strongly Do</label>
</div>  
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="q[0]"  value="two">
  <label class="form-check-label">I Do</label>
</div>
       <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="q[0]"  value="three">
  <label class="form-check-label">I Somewhat Do</label>
</div>
       <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="q[0]" value="four">
  <label class="form-check-label">I Don't</label>
</div>
       <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="q[0]" value="five">
  <label class="form-check-label">I Strongly Don't</label>
</div>  
    </div>
        </div>    
           
    <div class="border-secondary border border-0 shadow-lg border-secondary mt-3">
    <p class="p-3 bg-opacity-10 mb-0 w400 ">2. I organize and protect all my financial statements and online login details securely & This information is available to my spouse </p>     
    <div class="bg-success p-3 shadow-lg text-dark bg-opacity-10">       
       <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="q[1]"  value="one" required>
  <label class="form-check-label">I Strongly Do</label>
</div>  
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="q[1]"  value="two">
  <label class="form-check-label">I Do</label>
</div>
       <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="q[1]"  value="three">
  <label class="form-check-label">I Somewhat Do</label>
</div>
       <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="q[1]" value="four">
  <label class="form-check-label">I Don't</label>
</div>
       <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="q[1]"  value="five">
  <label class="form-check-label">I Strongly Don't</label>
</div>  
    </div>
        </div>
           
        
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-md" data-mdb-ripple-color="dark">Check</button>           
           </form> ```
````

and so on...

I have been trying to solve this for the last few hours but I could not be able to find the solution. Using this I can make some other conditions based on the user information.

Thanks.

Comment: PHP will read q[0] and q[1] as an array like so: `$_POST['q']`. Reading a parameter from a superglobal like this will usually be a string. But when the name contains brackets like this, it instead is interpreted as an array within PHP. So you could do `count($_POST['q']);` If you want one of the radio's values though then you'd do for example: `echo $_POST['q'][0];` or `echo $_POST['q'][1];` etc.

Comment: Please learn to use arrays, instead of "numbered variable names."

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A very uninformative description of your problem. Since you have radio buttons in the form, only one value will be returned to you in one position of the q[n] array. And if you need to count how many radio buttons have been returned, just try

```
count(q);
```